# jQuery onclick hide its parent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to hide `<li>` tag on `<a>` tag click with jQuery.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="'>Something</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="'>Something</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="'>Something</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In other words if someone clicks on link(`<a></a>`) its parent `<li>` gets hidden.

Comment: I wonder there are about 5 answers and on one is using jQuery "on"?

Comment: And none of the answers were written by users with low reputation.

Answer (score 7):

```
(function() {
  $("ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

also try the "one" jQuery function

```
(function() {
  $("ul li a").one('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @MarianZburela +1 for using "one" which i never heard of ever

Comment: nice example the one function, I'll remember it for future use

Comment: thanks, I'm glad we all learn something new or something better

Comment: @chris No...that's not how that selector works; it's simply a more specific way of targeting only the `<a>` links, the others aren't in the matched set.

Answer (score 4):

Handle the event with [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and then use the [.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide(); // this is the link element that was clicked
})
```

The code above assumes that the link is contained directly in the list element (`<li>`). If that isn't the case you can pass a selector to the `.parent` method like this:

```
$(this).parent("li").hide();
```

This will find go through the ancestors of your link and return the one that is a `<li>`.

**Returning false**

Normally, when you click an `<a>` tag the browser will navigate to the href of the tag. If you don't want that you can either `return false;` from the click handler or add an href that returns false: `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>`. There's more discussion about this [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-tag-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).

**There are many different ways to do this**

You might need variations of the code because:

- You probably have other links on the page that you don't want to hide the parent of. This is why it makes sense to use "ul li a" as the selector instead of "a" - it will only match the links that are inside a list
- You can use the `.preventDefault()` of the event object instead of returning false to prevent the browser from changing the address
- Since the link will be hidden after being clicked you can also use the [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method - it will remove the event handler after the link has been clicked. Don't do this if you plan to show the link again later on.
- You can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click` if your list is dynamic, i.e. you will use Javascript to add links to it
- Some answerers have wrapped the code in what's called a self-invoking function. It looks like this: `(function() { /* code */})(jQuery);`. I would not recommend this for beginners, although it will help you structure your code later on. Basically it helps you avoid unwanted side-effects in your code and allows you to use [.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this which hides the parents `li` and prevents the default action of clicking on the hyperlink. See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to target the element's parent, and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide it. See the jQuery documentation for details on these functions' uses. You should also use [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the browser from following the link.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to use `return false;`

```
  $('a').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().hide();
      return false;
  });​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DnwSE/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "a" ).click( function(){
    $( this ).parent().hide();
    return false;
} );
```

working example can be found here
http://jsfiddle.net/shinyakoizumi/aQanZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').hide();
});
```